# 2ndQuadrant BDR installation not working anymore

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-bdr

I previously used the following to install BDR (9.4) on Ubuntu:

```sh
echo "deb http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/bdr/apt/ trusty-2ndquadrant main" > "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/2ndquadrant.list"
wget --quiet -O - http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/bdr/apt/AA7A6805.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http:// apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" > "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
wget --quiet -O - https:// www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install bdr-9.4
```

Since the end of May when I make use of this, it only installs normal PostgreSQL.
I've tried this on Ubuntu 14.04, 15.10 and 16.04.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show error logs (postgresql.log)?

Comment: Here is the output on the following command:
apt-get -y install bdr-9.4 | tee log.

The output is too much so I have shared it on this link:

http://wikisend.com/download/842626/log.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure about this, but it seems that BDR is build into PostgreSQL, since I added a `shared_preload_library` like this:
`shared_preload_libraries = 'bdr'`, it seems to be working the same as BDR or maybe better.